# Rails/Mongoid database migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, rails-migrations

I am currently working on a rails app where we are using mongoid/mongoDB on the back-end.  I understand that I don't need ActiveRecord like migration to migrate the schema, but I do need to migrate data as I change mongoid model definitions.  Is anyone else out there running into the same scenario, if so how are you handling it?

Comment: https://github.com/adacosta/mongoid_rails_migrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom rake task to migrate the data as needed

Comment: Thanks.  I had thought of that, but I need this to be run once.

Comment: I dont follow.  You can easily run a rake task once or as many times as you want.  Run it once and then delete the task.

Comment: So I want it to be run once and then have some sort of record that it was run so it never will be run again as long as that record stays in the database.  However, I didn't think of just removing the code once it's been run.

Comment: well, you could make your rake task smart and check for a "migration" record in your db and just use conditions.  So inside your rake task "if flag < 1" then run migration step one then update the flag to 1.  If flag < 2 then run migration step 2 and update flag to 2, etc...

Answer (score 8):

Even though you're not making schema changes, you may need to move data between fields, or remove fields that are no longer used in the codebase. It's nice to have migrations that you can run when you deploy new code. I recommend using a gem called [`mongoid_rails_migrations`](https://github.com/adacosta/mongoid_rails_migrations). This provides you with migration generators like you're used to and provides some organization to migrating data.

```
class MyMigration < Mongoid::Migration

  def self.up
    MyModel.all.each do |model|
      # label was renamed to name
      model.set :name, model[:label] # copy the data from the old field to the new one
      model.remove_attribute :label # remove the old field from the document
      model.save!
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Just a heads up, a built in way of doing this is `MyModel.all.rename(label: :name)`. This performs an atomic $rename and will give you far better performance than manually stepping through and saving. +1 for `mongoid_rails_migrations` :)

Answer (score 0):

This question addresses the same issue of creating custom migrations in a mongoid setup.

[Runtime changing model with mongodb/mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724512/runtime-changing-model-with-mongodb-mongoid)

Answer (score 0):

I had the some scenario recently, where I have to do some data migration only once (basically update dirty data);
So what I did have a mongoid migrations in /db/migrate/ and override the db:migrate task so that it creates a collection in mongo db of that app itself, say "migrations", that record the migration that got fired, with that, none of the migration will run again, and you can keep adding migrations with some hierarchy (if in case migration is interdependent).